# Maxima variable ranges

Tags: maxima

I have the following function

[image]

but I don't know how to set ranges for my x variable, I would like to set it x=[-8,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say `assume(x > -8, x < 6)` although I don't think `max` can make use of that to find the maximum of that expression over that interval.